# Jetpack Compose: How to Preserve ViewModel State When Navigating Between Screens?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel, jetpack-compose-navigation

In the provided setup, I encounter an issue when navigating between Screen 1 and Screen 2 in my Jetpack Compose application. Here's a breakdown of the problem:

On Screen 1, I have a TextField that updates the viewModel and displays the updated viewModel.uiState.name in screen1_1 as the viewModel state is passed in as an arg

```
screen1_1(
    name = viewM.uiState.name
)
```

When I click on the screen 2 button, it navigates to screen 2 and displays the correct name as it is passed via navController.navigate("screen2/${viewM.uiState.name}")

however when I click navigate to screen 1 from screen 2, screen1_1 resets to empty?

How can I persist the viewModel state when I navigate back to screen 1

```
NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "screen1") {
    composable("screen1") { screen1(navController) }
    composable("screen2/{name}") { backStackEntry ->
        val name = backStackEntry.arguments?.getString("name") ?: ""
        screen2(navController, name)
    }
}

@Composable
fun screen1(navController: NavHostController) {
    val viewM: MyView = viewModel()

    Column {
        TextField(value = viewM.uiState.name, onValueChange = { viewM.updateName(it) })
        screen1_1(
            name = viewM.uiState.name
        )
        Button(onClick = { navController.navigate("screen2/${viewM.uiState.name}") }) {
            Text(text = "screen 2")
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun screen1_1(name: String) { Text(text = "Hello1 $name!") }

@Composable
fun screen2(navController: NavHostController, name: String) {
    Column {
        Text(text = "Name: $name", style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyLarge)
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
        Button(onClick = { navController.navigate("screen1") }) {
            Text(text = "Navigate to Screen 1")
        }
    }
}


data class MyData(var name: String = "")

class MyView(private val state: SavedStateHandle) : ViewModel() {
    @OptIn(SavedStateHandleSaveableApi::class)
    var uiState by state.saveable {
        mutableStateOf(MyData(""))
    }
    private set

    fun updateName(name: String) {
        this.uiState = uiState.copy(name = name)
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use ```saveState = true``` in navController.navigate().

Comment: there is no saveState param in navigate()

Answer (score 1):

When you run `navController.navigate("screen1")` in your screen2 you are not actually going back to screen1 but start a new screen1 so instead of `navController.navigate("screen1")` use `navController.navigateUp()`